# Excel VBA Web Price Data Capture

Tags: vba, excel

Here is my project:
1. I have a spreadsheet containing part/model numbers in a specific column
2. I wish to perform a Google Search for each part number and the word "price"
3. From the initial Google search result, I want to perform a Regex search for US Currency prices and populate a separate column with the average of returned prices for each part number and exclude all other html. The html pricing data is not necessarily in tables.

I am fairly familiar with Excel and have some familiarity with VBA. I have been able to code most of the above project, but I am having some difficulty extracting just the regex matches from the web page. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?  Can you post the code?

Answer (score 0):

Please see below:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim reg As New RegExp
    reg.Pattern = "\$\d+.?\d?\d?"

    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Range("A1:A1000") = "" ' erase previous data
    Range("A1").Select

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.Visible = True
    'IE.Navigate "https://www.google.com/" ' should work for any URL
    IE.Navigate "https://www.google.com/?_rd=ssl#q=" & "DNR-12-1-G Price"
    Do While IE.Busy = True Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    'IE.Document.getElementById("lst-ib").Value = "DNR-12 Price"

    'Do While IE.Busy = True Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    'SendKeys ("{ENTER}")   

    IE.ExecWB 17, 0 '// SelectAll
    IE.ExecWB 12, 2 '// Copy selection
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    'MsgBox (Continue)
    IE.Quit

End Sub
```